# Login to authenticated users

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a 2 textbox for username and password and a button. I want to allow authenticated users to login and redirect to another page and display welcome authenticated username.Or else display the message Invalid username.How to perform this using session and connect to database.How to configure with database. Please help me.

```
My code is
```

```
        <div id="loginbox">
            <div align="center" style="width: 100%;">


            </div>--%>
            <br />

                        <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text"   
id="username" /></li>
   <label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password" />

<input type="button" runat="server" value="Login">


</form>

My .cs code

protected void btnLogin_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connect = "Data Source=ST0022;Initial Catalog=QuickMove_Globe;Persist   
Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=good";
    string query = "Select Count(*) From Common.Users Where UserID = ? And Password =   
?";
    int result = 0;
    SqlConnection con= new SqlConnection(connect);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserID",username.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", password.Value);
            con.Open();
            Session["User"] = username.Value;
            result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("TestPortalPage.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lbluser.Text = "Invalid credentials";
    }


}
```

Comment: what have you tried? this is just the HTML/.aspx code which you have shared.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is trivial and you could have found the answer if you have searched first.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web.Security;
public partial class Account_Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
SqlConnection conn  = new SqlConnection  ("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=E:\\Raugh\\asp\\Login\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //click event of login button
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT u_id, u_pass from [user] where u_id = '"+UserName.Text+"' and u_pass='"+Password.Text+"'");
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.Read() == true)
    {
        Session.Timeout = 1;
        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
        //Response.Write("<script Language='JavaScript'> alert('Logged In')</script>");
        conn.Close();
    }
    else
    {

        Response.Write("<script Language='JavaScript'> alert('Log In Failed')</script>");
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/19303/updated-simple-asp.net-login-page) might help put you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks sir but i want to pass the entered username through session.

Comment: pas the entered username through session but where do you want to pass

Comment: I want to pass in another aspx page in one label.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Check this article

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2012/06/login-page-form-example-in-aspnet.html

and passing username through sessions is simple

`Session["User"] = username;`

in the redirected page use this in what ever control you placed, for example if it is a label

```
if(Session["User"]!=null)
{
label1.Text=Session["User"].ToString();
}
//    else
//  {
//    label1.Text="Invalid Username;
//    }
```

else condition is not needed in your case as you will redirect when the credentials are matched.

your code should be

`string strCon = "Data Source=ST0022;Initial Catalog=QuickMove_Globe;Persist

Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=good";
        string strSelect = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM youtablename WHERE yourcolumnname = @Username AND yourcolumnname = @Password";`

Comment: Error is Invalid object name "users". in line int result = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); of ur given worked out example in csharpdotnetfreak.Please tell me what is the problem

Comment: Instead of Users mention ur table name there